# What is the purpose of SVG, and why are they used in games?

Tags: svg

What is the purpose of the SVG image format?  Why we are they used in games?  How do you create SVG images?

Comment: How is that related to android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is not an image file format. It is a file format for storing vector graphics.

Comment: To add to it, svg contains vector and they could be used not only for graphics. One could build levels and use svg to create regions, walls, and other things. Then he'd have to parse svg and convert it for its game. The nice thing is that you only need a svg editor to build levels for a 2d game

Comment: Create a new question explaining your project and what you want to achieve. Answer may or may not be related to SVG.